# How to concat a number with a word in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, casting

How to concat a number with a word in MySQL?

I'd like the result be like "2013good" but the below query returns just "2013"

I tried these:

```
SELECT (CAST(2013 as char(100)) + 'good' ) as title;

SELECT (CAST(2013 + 'good' as char(100))) as title;
```

Comment: Please note that in MySQL (and most SQL dialects if I'm not wrong) [+](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_plus) is only the addition operator.

Comment: Are you using PHPMyAdmin? It sometimes returns strings as 'blob'. You can usually fix this by expanding that column in the user interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CONCAT`

```
SELECT CONCAT(2013, 'good') as title;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7263)

or `CONCAT_WS`

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', 2013, 'good') as title;
```

- [MySQL CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [MySQL CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Comment: thanks but it returns as BLOB, so now need to convert blob to varchar?

Comment: you are using lower version of `MySQL` right? try converting `INT` to string, `SELECT CONCAT(CAST(2013 AS CHAR(5)), 'good') as title`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(2013, 'good') as title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Which sql Server you are using? If not MS SQL 2012 - CONCAT function won't work.

Try use this:

```
SELECT (CAST(2013 as VARCHAR(255)) + 'good' ) as title;
```

Comment: the question is tagged with `MySQL`.

Comment: sorry, missed that tag and supposed that it's MS.